# Cannot convert String to Integer in Android Studio / Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a function that receives a number (milliseconds to be precise) via Bluetooth.

```
byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
readBufferPosition = 0;

started = "";
int myInt;
if (data != "") {
  try{
    myInt = new Integer(data);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(myInt);
  }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.err.println("NumberFormatException "+ ex.getMessage());
  }
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

The above try throws:

```
NumberFormatException Invalid int: "8250
```

I think the data received contains more then just the milliseconds, but how can I find that out, when I do

```
myLabel.setText(data);
```

it shows me: `8250`

Any ideas?

Comment: try `new Integer(data.trim());` can be a `\n`

Comment: try 
     `myInt = Integer.valueOf(data);`

Comment: @ Luis Felipe Kaufmann da silva perfect, that was it...

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is a String. When you try to form an Integer later, this fails. You need to use this:
`myInt = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(data));`